# Не получается спарсить Инт с get запроса

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, tomcat

Проблема: подаю на сервлет запрос в запросе есть значение id, но на сервлете в doget не получается спарсить id и по id уже выбрать из базы определённый "ивент". .getEvent(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("eventId")));

```
     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Enter doget");
    EventService eventService = new EventService();
    try {
        Event event = eventService.getEvent(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("eventId"))); //==========event = null;
//            System.out.println("Event:"+event.getName()+"ID:"+ event.getId());
            request.setAttribute("event", event);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/editEvent.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Перехожу я на данный сервлет с страницы index.jsp

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/editEvent?eventId=${event.id}">Edit</a>
```

по debug'у у меня event = null, по этому он ничего не может получить. Не могу понять. Буду благодарен за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Ясно, что выдавало NullFormatterException могу ошибиться, потому что у нас значение по запросу ГЕТ было получено, но так как в контроллере в getEvent концовка `return null;`
То он нам и выбивал. Вот такая вот ошибка)